# HTML5 UTF-8 Encoding Doesn't Work Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, .net-core

I am using .net core 2.0 in my current web application. I return some data by using `ViewData` and show it in current view. The thing is, my UTF-8 characters are not showed correctly.

For example, I wanted to show `ÖZTÜRK` but view returned `&#xD6;ZT&#xDC;RK` value.

I tried using `<meta charset="utf-8">` in my `<head>` tag. Also, I changed file Encoding UTF-8 BOM to UTF-8. I also have latest version of Chrome so my browser shouldn't be in my application's way.

So, what could be the real problem here?

Here is my code:

```html
@{
    var requestModel = ViewData["RequestModel"] as RequestModel;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />

</head>
<body>
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, null, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @style = "padding:5px 20px;", @id = "save-form" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group" id="emailAddressDiv">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">EmailAddress</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "employeeName" })
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, String.Empty, new { @class = "help-block" })
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Surname</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Surname, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "employeeName" })
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Surname, String.Empty, new { @class = "help-block" })
            </div>
        </div>       
    }

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var name;
            var surname;
            var emailAddress;

            debugger;

            @if (mapResponse.CurrentEmployee != null)
            {
                @:name = '@requestModel.Name';
                @:surname = '@requestModel.SurName';
                @:emailAddress = '@mapResponse.EmailAddress';
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is server side. If you are connecting to a database then set the connection to UTF-8 too.

Comment: When I put a breakpoint to `var requestModel = ViewData["RequestModel"] as RequestModel;` line, the values in `var requestModel ` seem normal. I think the wrong encoding happen in between `script` tags (in javascript) but I am not sure. But I am now sure values from server side are returned just how I want them.